# How to make named scope work in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am studying Rails and reading a tutorial with practical examples, that I'm trying out on my PC (I have Rails 4.1.1). In the named scopes chapter, 2 scopes are added in the Subject model:

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :visible, lambda { where(:visible => true) }
    scope :invisible, -> { where(:visible => false) }
end
```

If I then go to the app root and enter `rails console`, then type `Subject.visible`, I get this error:
`irb(main):020:0> Subject.visible
NoMethodError: undefined method visible for #<Class:0x4df5068>
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in method_missing
        from (irb):20`

How can I make this work?
For the reference, commands like `s = Subject.where(:visible => true)` do work. I am having trouble with the named scopes only. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Try giving a different name for `visible` scope. As it stands both `scope name` and `attribute name` are same.So Rails may be confused.

Comment: Did you `reload!` console after making changes in the Model?

Comment: I should have reloaded the console, you are right, Santosh, that was it. beginner's mistake. Thank you! Also to Pavan.